# Spring Boot 3 Build vs Runtime Initialization Hints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

I am working on creating an internal library/starter for my team that will add support for creating native images, providing all of the hints that our currently unsupported dependencies will need. I really like providing the metadata via code (using RuntimeHintsRegistrar), but there are also certain classes that need to be initialized at build time for whatever reason.

Right now I'm passing the --initialize-at-build-time and the classes to the Spring Boot Maven Plugin via the BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS, but ideally I'd like to avoid each consuming app having to include this in their own POM's plugin configuration.

I also understand that I can go more low-level and provide the argument inside of the META-INF/native-image directory in a native-image.properties file, but I'm not sure whether that will play nice with the Spring-provided RuntimeHintsRegistrar effectively creating that underneath the covers.

What is the best way to tell native-image the classes that should be initialized at build time without each consuming app having to pass it in their own POM? Also, if I use the GraalVM tracing agent to generate hints, will those hints play nicely with the ones that RuntimeHintsRegistrar generates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So far.. I ran the native-image goal to generate the META-INF/native-image files, and I'm grabbing my metadata from that to start consolidating each set of dependency-specific hints.

The Args= commands where I tell it which classes to init at build-time are being consolidated nicely at AOT compilation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answered by Sebastien Deleuze from the Spring team during their last online conference. Answer is, we should not worry about trying to initialize classes at build time. Providing enough hints to get the library/code flow working effectively adds native-image support.